# Android app hangs

Tags: java, android

Hey i'm brand new to programming and i need some help,
i'm doing a project for school and it's an android app where the user inputs words to a text field and then those words are used to create a story, like mad libs. I can not seem to see what is wrong with my code here when i debug on my phone it just shows a white screen. Could someone point out to me what i'm doing wrong? thanks...

```
MainActivity.java:

package com.joe.madlibs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText Noun, Adj, Name, Verb, Verb2, Noun2, Adj2;
    Button Submit;
    TextView Story;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Noun = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noun1);
        Adj = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.adjective1);
        Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name1);
        Verb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.verb1);
        Verb2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.verb2);
        Noun2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noun2);
        Adj2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.adj2);
        String noun = Noun.getText().toString();
        String adj = Adj.getText().toString();
        String name = Name.getText().toString();
        String verb = Verb.getText().toString();
        String verb2 = Verb2.getText().toString();
        String noun2 = Noun2.getText().toString();
        String adj2 = Adj2.getText().toString();
        Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}

activity_main.xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/noun1"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/noun" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/verb1"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/name1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/name1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/storyBox"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/verb" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/adjective1"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/noun1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/noun1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/verb1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/adjective" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name1"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/noun1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/noun1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/verb2"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/verb" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/adj2"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/verb1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/verb1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Adjective" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/noun2"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/verb2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/verb2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Noun" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Click here to get your story!" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/storyBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/noun2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="This is where your story will go!"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>


Manifest.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Joe.madlibs"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.Joe.madlibs.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Probably a wrong manifest. Post that as well

Comment: You're Activity and layout look fine. Please post your Manifest.

Comment: Have you ever tested on emulator?

Comment: Not your problem but your `LinearLayout` appears to be useless

Comment: It appears on my phone when I run it, although, I removed the dimensions and string resources as I obviously don't have those defined. Are you saying you get no layout at all when you first run it and no logcat errors? If so, you might want to test on an emulator or different device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm... where are you instantiating your Submit button before trying to set an onClickListener on it?  I see where you declare it, but you aren't instantiating it.

Add:

```
Submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

right before

```
Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

and watch.  It's gonna be like magic.

One more thing about coding conventions (style):  when you name your instance variables, use the headlessCamelCase convention.  Names with CamelCase/InitCaps (first letter of each word capitalized) should only be used when you name your class (the pattern for an object) as opposed to when you refer to an instance of that class (the actual object).

Wrong:

```
// An instance of Button class
Button Submit;
```

Right:

```
// An instance of Button class:
Button submit;
```

When it comes to compound names (more than one word), headlessCamelCase means you capitalize the first letter of each word, except the first word.

Right:

```
// An instance of Button class:
Button myVeryElderlyMotherJustSatUponNapoleonsSubmitButton;
```

Comment: I believe the homework tag as been removed. Also, the button not being instantiated won't keep it from showing the layout...no magic

Comment: The question is, if it's an assignment, why was it removed?  My mind is boggled, but that's not such an uncommon thing...

Comment: Not removed from this post...removed from SO

Comment: Ah, I see... the homework tag was nuked (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) back in September.

Comment: still isn't working... tried on an emulator and still doesn't work. Should i post the manifest.xml?

Comment: I added only that single line and it worked.  The actual error is 04-26 00:13:23.955: E/AndroidRuntime(505): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 00:13:23.955: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at com.marsatomic.stackoverflow.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
Line 39, of course, is the call to the Submit button that hasn't been instantiated.

Comment: See how you have Joe capitalized in the package name in the manifest but not capitalized in the package declaration in MainActivity.java?  Fix that and keep the change that I pointed out in the answer.

Comment: Thanks i can't believe i missed that, thanks so much for the help everyone

Comment: Now if you would be so kind as to accept my answer to replace the 2 points that someone cost me by downvoting a correct answer, there will be justice in this world.  Thanks.

Comment: definitely, not sure who'd downvote you...you were just helping out. people suck I guess...